# Apache REQUEST_URI prepends parent path when evaluating RewriteCond directives

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a site running on Apache 2.4 that has two .htaccess files like so:

/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ public/    [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

/public/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    ## Redirect PDF files to application (bootstrap starts at index.php) for authentication
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(protected/path/.*\.pdf)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The root level .htaccess is supposed to force all requests into the /public folder (and it does). The `public/.htaccess` is supposed to handle other application-specific things (like redirecting certain requests to the CMS/application bootstrap index.php). It does that successfully as well.

My problem is the `%{REQUEST_URI}` value on that `RewriteCond`. It's evaluating to `/public/protected/path/whatever.pdf` whenever I try to access (in a browser) `http://somedomain.com/protected/path/whatever.pdf`. I am expecting it to evaluate to `/protected/path/whatever.pdf` and thus match the regex condition. Obviously, my parent .htaccess that forces all requests into the `public` folder is interfering, but I can't figure out a way to make it stop doing that.

I realize that I can combine these two things, or put the `RewriteCond` in the root-level .htaccess like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    ## Redirect PDF files to application (bootstrap starts at index.php) for authentication
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(protected/path/.*\.pdf)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) public/index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]

    RewriteRule ^$ public/    [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

However, I'm looking for a solution that lets me keep the two files and simply "fix" the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable value so it does NOT include the parent "public" path. I feel like I'm missing something trivial with a simple flag or `RewriteBase` or similar directive somewhere. Any thoughts would be very appreciated.

Comment: The more dynamic configuration files you use the slower your http server gets. Best actually is not to use such files at all, but to place such rules in the http servers (virtual) host configuration.

Comment: Myb change the /public/.htaccess to `RewriteRule ^/public/(protected/path/.*\.pdf)$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,QSA,L]` ? If that's what you where aiming for?